# How to disable Android TV Support in my app? Manifest complaining about missing LEANBACK_LAUNCHER

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-tv, disable

I've been searching for a way to disable Android TV Support from the manifest. I know our app is incompatible and I've read that even when you aim at supporting Android TV, apps turn out unsupported anyways.

However, I have not found a way to stop the Manifest from asking for a INTENTBACK_LAUNCHER. I don't want to define one because I know that our app is not compatible with TV.

These are the warnings that I get right now:

> Expecting uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" tag.
>
> Expecting an activity to have android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER intent filter.
>
> Hardware feature android.hardware.touchscreen not explicitly marked as optional

So when I try to supply the expected tags, even if I say the following:

> uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="true"

It still sends a warning that it might not be supported by all TVs, which is nothing else than a warning but really annoying because I deliberately don't want to support Android TV. And even after I still get the LEANBACK_LAUNCHER intent filter warning as well.

Wouldn't requiring a touchscreen rid me of the manifest asking for a LEANBACK_LAUNCHER? I guess some TVs have touchscreens?

Anybody knows how to explicitly disable Android TV Support?

Thank you,

Comment: Do you happen to have a `banner` attribute on the `<application>` element in your manifest?

Comment: No. No banner attribute in application element, unfortunately.

Comment: any solution here?

Comment: same issue on api 33

Answer (score 2):

Remove this from your manifest, and your error will be gone

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: While your answer might be correct, this is exactly what other old answers tell to do, for instance check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57068309/14291243) one.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the lint checks by adding the `tools:ignore` attribute to your manifest as follows:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.sampleapp"
    tools:ignore="ImpliedTouchscreenHardware,MissingLeanbackLauncher,MissingLeanbackSupport">
```

Answer (score 0):

I stuck in this but i think its just a bug that can not recognize my app it isn't an android TV app!

for now i add these lines in manifest and 2 of 3 warnings fixed

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
```

Unfortunately i don't any solution for last warning yet

> Expecting an activity to have android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER intent filter.
>
> An application intended to run on TV devices must declare a launcher
>   activity for TV in its manifest using a
>   android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER intent filter.  Issue id:
>   MissingLeanbackLauncher

I can add LEANBACK_LAUNCHER but i don't want to! because i want to disable android tv support at all.

If you want, create an Activity and add this lines in manifest

```
  <activity
    android:name="com.example.android.TvActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

  </activity>
```

And now give you error to add banner. add this line

```
<application
  android:banner="@drawable/banner" >
```

Comment: this doesn't actually remove support.  You're just making it so that support is "optional" and that will still bloat  your apk.  It needs to be removed from the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

remove Leanback from your dependencies e.g.
//implementation `'androidx.leanback:leanback:1.0.0'`

remove from manifest

```
<!--uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback" android:required="false" /-->
<!--category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" /-->
<!--application android:banner="@drawable/banner" -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever library you're importing that brought the problem, exclude leanback from it

```
implementation("com.library.using.tv:foo") {
    exclude group: 'androidx.leanback', module: 'leanback'
}
```

If you don't suspect any library then [check your dependency tree](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#view-dependency-tree).